# Java: How to solve error for 'Could not load main class'

Tags: java, classpath

Despite there being numerous versions of this question, it still happens to come up with no single correct or straight forward answer.

I have the same problem and cannot execute my project.

I have my file on my desktop and it is called

`login.java`

I have run

```
javac Login.java
```

and now have two `class` files named `Login$1.class` and `Login.class`.

I get the error `Could not find or load main class Login.java`.

Please for the love of god can somebody answer this in a methodical way for java newbie.

I will happily follow and let you know what happens with each step.

Kind regards.

Here is the code

```
package login;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Login extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Welcome");
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

    Text scenetitle = new Text("Welcome");
    scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
    grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

    Label userName = new Label("User Name:");
    grid.add(userName, 0, 1);

    TextField userTextField = new TextField();
    grid.add(userTextField, 1, 1);

    Label pw = new Label("Password:");
    grid.add(pw, 0, 2);

    PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
    grid.add(pwBox, 1, 2);

    Button btn = new Button("Sign in");
    HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
    hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
    grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 4);

    final Text actiontarget = new Text();
    grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            actiontarget.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
            actiontarget.setText("Sign in button pressed");
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

I run

```
javac Login.java
```

Which works fine. Then I run

```
java login
```

I have also tried

```
java Login
```

With an Uppercase 'L' but still get

`Error: Could not find or load main class login`

Comment: What is the code of `Login.class` ? Plus this has nothing to do with `JavaFX`

Comment: You're running `java Login.java` but you should run `java Login`.

Comment: It sounds like what @Kenney said, but what specifically did you type to try to run your login java program? javac Login.java will compile the program, java <file name here> will run the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the package line, or put your file in a directory named login.
I made a simple file as so:

```
public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Ran.");
    }
}
```

I then ran the following which works:

```
javac Login.java
java Login
```

I also made it work by creating a directory login/ with the package login:

login/Login.java contents are:

```
package login;
public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Ran.");
    }
}
```

Then ran:

```
mkdir login
vi login/Login.java
javac login/Login.java
java login.Login
```

Works for me.

Edit:
As long as you have JavaFX, the same structure will make your code work. There is nothing unique about JavaFX that will affect your compilation. Your issue is just a directory structure + compilation issue.

Comment: Also, consider using an IDE, (Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc.) since an IDE will help you organize your code and deal with running with the correct class paths, etc.

Comment: I removed the line 'package login' and it seemed to have worked because it printed "ran"

Comment: but the application doesn't launch now!

Comment: Now that it is compiling and executing, that issue is resolved. Now, you just need to make the JavaFX part work. I'd recommend compiling a simple JavaFX sample to try.

Comment: Also, remember to recompile if you plan on doing it all manually with javac.
If on a Unix style system, you can simplify by running 

javac Login.java && java Login

This will ensure that you always compile before running.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably rename your "login.java" file to "Login.java", and since this is in the package "login", you need to go up one directory, and run

```
java login.Login
```

**EDIT:** You mentioned this file is on your desktop, you need to put it in a folder named "login" since this file is in the login package